# Limit of $(n!)^{1/(n!)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Wolfram gives me $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{1/(n!)} = 1$

What is the analytical approach to compute this limit?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n} = 1$?

Comment: Ah yes, using that property makes this trivial. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHOD 1:**

There have already been a couple of quality answers posted.  But, I thought that it would be instructive to see a simple application of the Gamma function.  Recall $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$. Then,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(n!^{1/n!}\right)&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(e^{\frac{\log \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}}\right)\tag 1\\\\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\log \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\right)}\tag 2\\\\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)}\right)}\tag 3\\\\
&=1\tag 4
\end{align}$$

---

**NOTES:**

In arriving at $(1)$, we used the definition of $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ along with $x=e^{\log x}$ with $x=\Gamma(n+1)^{1/\Gamma(n+1)}$

To go from $(1)$ to (2)$, we used the continuity of the exponential to bring the limit inside the argument.

To go from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we used L'Hospital's Rule.

To go from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we observed again that $\Gamma(n+1) \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

---

**METHOD 2:**

Here is another way to proceed without using L'Hospital's Rule. We have $a_n=n!^{1/n!}$.  Let $b_n=\log a_n$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
b_n&=\frac{\log n!}{n!}\\\\
&=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log k}{n!}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log (k/n)+\log n}{(n-1)!}
\end{align}$$

Note that the sum is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \log x dx=-1$.  Thus, the limit of $b_n$ is the same as $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log n}{(n-1)!}=0$.  And we recover the coveted limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}n!^{1/n!}=1}$$

Comment: If you use L'Hopital's on (2), then you should get a $(\Gamma(n+1))^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: @mihirsinghal That's untrue.  The derivatvive of the numerator is $\Gamma'/\Gamma$, while the derivative of the denominator is $\Gamma'$.  Thus the ratio that results is $1/\Gamma$, as asserted.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I made a mistake.

Comment: @MihirSinghal No worry.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV Note that the only properties of $Gamma$ used here are differentiability and divergence to infinity.  The actual properties of the function that interpolates factorial are inessential.

Comment: @ErickWong The task is to evaluate $\lim n!^{1/n!}$.  Inasmuch as $\Gamma (n+1)=n!$, this makes it completely equivalent.  I believe that you are observing that any differentiable function that approaches infinity is suitable.  Yes, that is true. But having the Gamma function representation of the factorial makes it more compelling than say just $n^{1/n}$, or $(n^2)^{1/n^2}$, don't you think?

Answer (score 7):

Let $x=n!$. Then the limit becomes 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{1/x} &= \exp\left(\ln\left(\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{1/x}\right)\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}\ln x\right) \\
&= \exp(0) & \text{by L'Hopital's Rule} \\
&= 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

It’s the same as

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{(\ln x)/x}\\
&=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\ln x)/x}\\
&=e^0\\
&=1\;.
\end{align*}$$

The second step is justified by the continuity of the exponential function.